# Remove partition and enlarge partition

Tags: partition

I am trying to delete my linux-swap partition /dev/sda5 and allocate the free space to /dev/sda6.

But when i try to delete sda5 GParted gives an error "You have to umount sda6".
But i can not umount sda6. I gives me the error "umount: /: target is busy"
If i reduce the size of sda5 i can not allocate the unallocated space to sda6.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to do this the right way?

I have a multi-boot system with windows and Linux. (Grub2)

[image]

Comment: Neither of those addresses his problem.

Comment: If you happen to be running a remote (no direct access) system, live media is of limited usefulness.  If the system had been setup to use LVM, you *could* have changed that swap partition to another chunk of the volume group containing **`/`**, and extended the filesystem with little impact.

Comment: @Dafnie, first you'll need to get the last sector of your swap partition. Review the output of `parted /dev/sda unit s print`. If the start/end sector range of your swap partition is not AFTER the start/end range of your `/` partition, abort this procedure. Otherwise make a note of the end sector of the swap partition. Next, turn off your swap partition with `swapoff -a`. Next, edit `/etc/fstab` and remove the entry for your swap partition...

Comment: ...Next, delete the swap partition with `parted /dev/sda rm  5` Removing that partition will likely change the partition number for `/`, so run `lsblk` to get the correct partition number for `/`. Next, resize the `/` partition with `parted /dev/sda unit s resizepart  ROOT_PART_NUMBER_HERE LAST_SECTOR_HERE`. Finally, you can grow the filesystem online with `resize2fs /dev/sdaROOT_PART_NUMBER_HERE`...

Comment: ...Before running any of these commends, I highly recommend you have backups for everything; Basically you accept the possibility of wrecking your entire disk. And that you read the documentation for the commands so you know what they do and can adjust accordingly.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa please post that as an answer now that the question has been reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the image, `sda6` is an ext4 partition that's mounted as `/`. That's the main node of your system, so it will stay busy as long as the system is up. You need either a live USB/DVD session or to connect the drive under another running system and perform the operation from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answars. I booted on a Linux USB and removed the swapdrive this way.
1. Disabled swap by rightkliking the swapdrive.
2. Unmount the swapdrive.
3. Delete the swapdrive.
4. expand the / drive
5. Edit /etc/fstab and remove the entry for your swap partition.

Comment: @Dafnie Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can remove your swap partition and use the free/unallocated space for your `/` partition.

### Warning

But first... Before running *any* of these commands, I insist you have backups for everything. This is so important it's worth mentioning twice: no backups? Do not proceed.

By proceeding you accept the possibility of wrecking your entire disk. That's the nature of manipulating partitions.

### Procedure

1. Get the last sector of your swap partition. Review the output of `parted /dev/sda unit s print`. If the start/end sector range of your swap partition is not AFTER the start/end range of your / partition, abort this procedure. Otherwise make a note of the end sector of the swap partition.
2. Turn off your swap partition with `swapoff -a`.
3. Edit `/etc/fstab` and remove the entry for your swap partition.
4. Delete the swap partition with `parted /dev/sda rm 5`. Removing that partition will likely change the partition number for `/`, so run `lsblk` to get the correct partition number for `/`.
5. Resize the `/` partition with `parted /dev/sda unit s resizepart ROOT_PART_NUMBER_HERE LAST_SECTOR_HERE`.
6. Grow the filesystem online with `resize2fs /dev/sdaROOT_PART_NUMBER_HERE`